# Whats wrong in this BST implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Why am I getting `false` while doing `search(7)`?
I tried recursive solution its working fine..
tried implementing with loop failed

```java
public class BST {

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node left , right;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = this.right = null;
        }
    }

    Node root;

    public BST() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        // create a new node and start iteration from root node
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        Node currentNode = this.root;

        while (true) {
            if (currentNode == null) {
                currentNode = newNode;
                break;
            }

            if (data < currentNode.data) { // if data is less go left
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            } else if (data > currentNode.data) {   // if data is greater go right
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            } else {    // do nothing for duplicates
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean search(int data) {
        Node currentNode = this.root;

        while (true) {
            if (currentNode == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (data == currentNode.data) {
                return true;
            } else if (data < currentNode.data) {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        BST tree = new BST();

        tree.insert(15);
        tree.insert(7);

        System.out.println(tree.search(7));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is inside the `insert` method - you are not inserting the nodes correctly inside the tree.

1. If the tree is empty, you should assign to `this.root`, not `currentNode`. Assigning to `currentNode` has no affect on `this.root`.

   Currently, your code **isn't inserting** any node inside the tree; it simply assigns the new node to the local variable of `insert` method, i.e. `currentNode`.
2. If the condition `data < currentNode.data` is true, then you need to check if the `currentNode.left` is `null` or not. If it is, then link the new node with the current node as shown below:

   ```
   currentNode.left = newNode;
   ```

   If `currentNode.left` is not `null`, then do the following:

   ```
   currentNode = currentNode.left;
   ```

   Currently, your code moves the `currentNode` to `null` and then assigns the `newNode` to the `currentNode` **without a reference to its parent node in the tree**.
3. Do step 2 for `data > currentNode.data` as well.

Change the implementation of the `insert` method as shown below:

```
public void insert(int data) {

    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    
    Node currentNode = this.root;

    while (true) {
        if (data < currentNode.data) {
            if (currentNode.left == null) {
                currentNode.left = newNode;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }
        } else if (data > currentNode.data) {
            if (currentNode.right == null) {
                currentNode.right = newNode;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what I was doing is moving the pointer to null with no reference to its parent Node right? That is way I was failing to create edges of the tree?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the problem. Other problem was that when tree is empty, your code didn't update the `this.root`; instead it assigned the `newNode` to the local variable of `insert` method, i.e. `currentNode`.